# How to insert a string which contains an "&"

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, sqlplus

How can I write an insert statement which includes the & character?  For example, if I wanted to insert "J&J Construction" into a column in the database.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I keep on forgetting this and coming back to it again! I think the best answer is a combination of the responses provided so far.

Firstly, & is the variable prefix in sqlplus/sqldeveloper, hence the problem - when it appears, it is expected to be part of a variable name.

SET DEFINE OFF will stop sqlplus interpreting & this way.

But what if you need to use sqlplus variables *and* literal & characters?

- You need SET DEFINE ON to make variables work
- And SET ESCAPE ON to escape uses of &.

e.g.

```
set define on
set escape on

define myvar=/forth

select 'back\\ \& &myvar' as swing from dual;
```

Produces:

```
old   1: select 'back\\ \& &myvar' from dual
new   1: select 'back\ & /forth' from dual

SWING
--------------
back\ & /forth
```

If you want to use a different escape character:

```
set define on
set escape '#'

define myvar=/forth

select 'back\ #& &myvar' as swing from dual;
```

When you set a specific escape character, you may see 'SP2-0272: escape character cannot be alphanumeric or whitespace'. This probably means you already have the escape character defined, and things get horribly self-referential. The clean way of avoiding this problem is to set escape off first:

```
set escape off
set escape '#'
```

Comment: np! as I said, I keep on forgetting this, so happy for the chance to record the 'comprehensive answer';-)

Comment: This [SQL*Plus FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#How_does_one_disable_interactive_prompting_in_SQL.2APlus.3F) provides a similar answer.

Answer (score 22):

If you are doing it from SQLPLUS use

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

to stop it treading & as a special case

Answer (score 17):

An alternate solution, use concatenation and the chr function:

```
select 'J' || chr(38) || 'J Construction' from dual;
```

Comment: You are missing the || after chr(38)

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax is

```
set def off;
insert into tablename values( 'J&J');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES('Jonhy''s Sport &'||' Fitness')
```

This query's output : **Jonhy's Sport & Fitness**

Answer (score 5):

There's always the chr() function, which converts an ascii code to string.

ie. something like:
INSERT INTO
 table
VALUES (
 CONCAT( 'J', CHR(38), 'J' )
)

Answer (score 5):

You can insert such an string as **'J'||'&'||'Construction'**.
It works fine.

```
insert into table_name (col_name) values('J'||'&'||'Construction');
```

Answer (score 4):

SET SCAN OFF is obsolete
http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/apc.htm

Answer (score 4):

In a program, always use a parameterized query. It avoids SQL Injection attacks as well as any other characters that are special to the SQL parser.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that using either of the following options works:

`SET DEF OFF`

or

`SET SCAN OFF`

I don't know enough about databases to know if one is better or "more right" than the other.  Also, if there's something better than either of these, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql plus then I think that you need to issue the command

```
SET SCAN OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
INSERT VALUES("J\&J Construction") INTO custnames;
```

(Untested, don't have an Oracle box at hand and it has been a while)

Comment: Then you'd have to have a special treatment for specifying a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using SQL/Plus, I highly recommend [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.nl/plsqldev.html)  it's much more than an SQL tool.

p.s. Some people prefer [TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Look, Andrew:

**"J&J Construction"**:

```
SELECT CONCAT('J', CONCAT(CHR(38), 'J Construction')) FROM DUAL;
```