# how to recify this problem in SQL PLUS?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with insertion scripts in SQL PLUS.In my insert scripts data contains '&' like this 'Rat&CAT'.When am run my script file using SQL PLUS Batch file .It is always promting this message  "Enter the Value of CAT:".Could any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152837/ (and others)

Answer (score 4):

Add this command at the start of your script:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
```

It will turn off variable substitution.