# Oracle Query with "&" special character

Tags: oracle, special-characters

I have an Oracle query that is blowing up when I have an "&D" in the where statement

```
select <field> from <table> where field = 'ABC&D';
```

The Oracle Variable window pops up asking for a value for :D.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a string which contains an "&"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152837/how-to-insert-a-string-which-contains-an)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, if you do not wish to use `SET` commands, is to use concatenation:

```
select <field> from <table> where field = 'ABC' || '&' || 'D';
```

Answer (score 6):

Turn off variable substitution via:

```
set define off
```

Then run your query. SQL*Plus is interpreting the &D as a runtime substitution variable.

Comment: @DCookie.....thank you.  However, I am running the query in a package.  I don't know where to but the SET code in a package.  Do u?

Comment: @MikeTWebb: You are running this in SQL*Plus. You run the SET before you call the package.