# Like with & in SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-like

In an SQL script which I have inherited, there the following where line, which I partially do not understand.

```
Where substr(hou.name,1,2) like '&Region%'
```

I understand the substr function, but I do not understand the `&Region` in the like clause.

Can anybody help me make sense of it?

Comment: If your SQL environment is an Oracle one, then "& is the variable prefix in sqlplus/sqldeveloper" as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152837/how-to-insert-a-string-which-contains-an. You should tag your question, if possible, with the correct RDMS-tag (SQL-SERVER, ORACLE, MySQL, Postgres, or ...) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what that does is take a variable that has been defined elsewhere and substitutes it into the statement. Assuming you are using Oracle, you can get a user input up front by using

```
ACCEPT Region PROMPT 'Enter region to be searched: '
```

or you can use a define statement to hard code it. Either way, once that variable is defined you can then use it by typing `&Region`. If someone types in "South" for example, then the compiler would see this as equivalent to

```
Where substr(hou.name,1,2) like 'South%'
```

And would thus give back results like South Carolina, South Dakota, etc.