# vertica UTF-8 character

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with a column whose type is varchar(32) the value it has is
`'Movies ＆ TV'` . This data is loaded by Copy command, when I query this table like

```
select * from activity where name='Movies & TV' (typed this value)
```

it won't return any record this is mainly because of & character there is something going on with this character.

When I tried

`Select ISUTF8(name) from activity it returns true`, which means the data is actually stored in the UTF-8 format.
`Select length(name) and length('Movies & TV')` are also same. However, when I paste these values in the vi editor and saw an extra space in the DB string.  In addition, the field name in activity table can have Chines characters too, which is stored correctly in DB now.

Any idea what is going on here? Should I specify explicit UTF-8 when loading the data?

Comment: Maybe the "culprit" is not '&'. Maybe you have some other (invisible but still UTF8 encoded) character in your database. Something like non-breakable-space for example...

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing it from SQLPLUS use

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

to stop it treading & as a special case.

An alternate solution, use concatenation and the `chr` function:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE name= 'Movies ' || chr(38) || ' TV';
```

Solution from:
[How to insert a string which contains an "&"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152837/how-to-insert-a-string-which-contains-an)

Comment: What SQLPLUS has to do with Vertica?